# Clicking on child elements gives undefined for onclick event reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-handling, dom-events

I have a component for restaurants list and I have an onClick event for every list-item. Everything is working fine except when I click any child element of the list item. It responds with nothing or undefined (I don't know because nothing is showing up in the console.)
Here is my component:

```
import React from "react";

class ResturantsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      reviews: {}
    };

  }
  handleReviews = e => {
    const reviewsList = this.props.resturants.find(
      resturant => resturant.id === e.target.id
    );
    console.log(reviewsList.reviews);
  };

  render() {
    let list = this.props.resturants.map(resturant => {
      return (
        <li
          key={resturant.id}
          id={resturant.id}
          className="resturant"
          onClick={this.handleReviews}
        >
          <div className="resturant__hero">
            <h1 className="resturant__name">{resturant.name}</h1>
            <img src={resturant.icon} alt="" className="resturant__icon" />
          </div>
          <div className="resturant__row">
            <p className="item">Rating</p>
            <p className="description">{resturant.rating || "N/A"}</p>
          </div>

        </li>
      );
    });
    return <div>{list}</div>;
  }
}

export default ResturantsList;
```

So the problem is I can only click on the padding of li to get accurate result otherwise it throws error. 
This behavior is new for me and very unexpected.

edit- 
Binding in the constructor is not the problem, I had that line but this is not real issue. My event working just fine but only when I click li and not any of its child.

Comment: Try initializing `this.handleReviews` inside the constructor, `constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      reviews: {}
    };
   this.handleReviews = this.handleReviews.bind(this);// add this line
  }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Use [e.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

Try using `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target` in your `handleReviews()`, like so:

```
handleReviews = e => {
    const reviewsList = this.props.resturants.find(
      resturant => resturant.id === e.currentTarget.id // <--- Here
    );
    console.log(reviewsList.reviews);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I’ve solved it by adding for each li’s a data-id attribute and binding the handleReviews method to this.

```
<li
      key={resturant.id}
      data-id={resturant.id}
      className="resturant"
      onClick={this.handleReviews}
>
```

And then in handleReviews I’ll get the element with (**e.currentTarget.dataset.id**):

```
  handleReviews = e => {
    const reviewsList = this.props.resturants.find(
      resturant => resturant.id === e.currentTarget.dataset.id
    );
  };
```

Comment: It worked with just e.currentTarget.id , so data-id would be unnecessary. Thanks man I appreciate your answer.